# Regex for data inside nested curly braces?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following record of data:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{conf/icsm/Ceccato07,
  author = {Mariano Ceccato},
  title = {Migrating Object Oriented code to Aspect Oriented Programming},
  booktitle = {ICSM},
  year = {2007},
  pages = {497--498},
  publisher = {IEEE},
  bibdate = {2008-11-18},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/icsm/icsm2007.html#Ceccato07},
  crossref = {conf/icsm/2007},
  owner = {Administrator},
  timestamp = {2009.04.30},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICSM.2007.4362668}
}
```

Is there a way that i can get the following matchings such that each line is a separate match

```
  conf/icsm/Ceccato07
  author = Mariano Ceccato
  title = Migrating Object Oriented code to Aspect Oriented Programming
  booktitle = ICSM
  year = 2007
  pages = 497--498
  publisher = IEEE
  bibdate = 2008-11-18
  bibsource = DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/icsm/icsm2007.html#Ceccato07
  crossref = conf/icsm/2007
  owner = Administrator
  timestamp = 2009.04.30
  url = http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICSM.2007.4362668
```

Here is my pattern which misses the first line match and doesn't bit get rid of the braces and the commas

```
string pattern = ".*[{].*}";
```

Comment: Yes there is...but what have you tried so far?

Comment: being that I'm not a big fan of regex, and being that you're having difficulty figuring this out, wouldn't string.Replace() be a slightly easier option?

Comment: Guys we need more down votes, and when you do just tell me why so maybe i can get it through my thick head.

Comment: Makes sense, now that I'm looking at the details of the record supplied :)

Comment: @user733659 show us what you have so far, that's probably the best way to get the downvotes to stop...

Comment: I have edited my question with the pattern i was trying to create

Comment: This is now a perfectly valid and good question, +1 and voted to reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression, in Singleline mode, will grab everything inside the two outside braces:

```
(?<=\{).*(?=\})
```

Then you can use C# to strip out the interior braces:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\{).*(?=\})", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var match = regex.Match(input);

return match.Value.Replace("{", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty);
```